# Disable 'Show live semantic errors' for C# in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

In Visual Studio 2013, I could un-check the option "Show live semantic errors" under Tools → Options → Text Editor → C# → Advanced.

This functionality is painfully distracting, and I would *love* to turn it off.  Unfortunately, this options was removed back in Visual Studio 2015, and is still not back in Visual Studio 2017.

Is there any way to somehow disable this option for 2017?  I have searched everywhere I can think of... Does anyone have any ideas?

The behavior I find distracting/frustrating/etc. is the constant visual notification that there is something wrong with my code. Specifically WHILE I am writing something...

As a very simply example:

```
/// <summary>
/// 
/// </summary>
public class MyClass
{
   public string DoSomething()
   {
   }
}
```

'DoSomething' will be identified (via red squiggly line) as not returning a value. If I am in the process of writing my method I don't want to be reminded it is wrong. This example, although rather simple, is an illustration of the problem. The real-time error-highlighting can get really distracting as things get more complicated. I know many have suggested making the 'squiggle' color the same as the background color. The problem there is that once I compile, I WOULD like to see those squiggles...

I have disabled all Analyzers at the solution level AND the project level.

Comment: As of Version 15.5.4 this is STILL not available... Anybody have ideas?

Comment: This feature was completely, thoroughly and irreversibly replaced by Roslyn in VS2015.  Hoping that you'll get that checkbox back is idle hope.  The rough replacement is live code analysis, turning that off is easy.  But whether that keeps you happy is hard to guess when you don't give an explicit example of behavior you don't like.

Comment: Added more detail for clarity

Answer (score 0):

You are not the only one to ask for this option ... You may take a look [here](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-ide/suggestions/12304638-enable-turning-off-roslyn-code-fixes) for confirmation

But according to one of the comment visible on that [link](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-ide/suggestions/12304638-enable-turning-off-roslyn-code-fixes), you may still disable the full solution analysis:

> IMHO, the new checkbox in VS2015 Update 3 which allows you to toggle
>   off/on the "Enable full solution analysis" option is a step in the
>   right direction
>   (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/mt709421(VS.140).aspx) - but
>   it still doesn't enable you to eliminate ALL solution analysis.

Answer (score 0):

Currently that is impossible. You can request to bring this feature back and present your argument in [How to disable live code compilation/analysis in Visual Studio 2017?](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/24513) Roslyn issue on GitHub.

There is no relevant option in Visual Studio. You can't change squiggle (wavy line) style because Visual Studio uses same style named Syntax Error both for design-time errors and compile-time errors. Roslyn that comes with Visual Studio ignores relevant registry keys. See [Performance considerations for large solutions](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/Performance-considerations-for-large-solutions) page in Roslyn GitHub Wiki. Although Language Service and Editor have relevant extension points, they wouldn't let you alter Visual Studio default behavior. See [Extending the Editor and Language Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/extending-the-editor-and-language-services) page on MSDN.